# send data collected on the internet instead of on the serial monitor (Nodemcu v3)

Tags: ip-address, sensors, esp8266, nodemcu, esp8266wifi

Good evening, 
I am working on a project on a brightness sensor (tsl2561). Not having arrived yet I used a photoresistor and a led and everything works perfectly. Practically, depending on the light seen by the photoresistor, the LED light is more or less strong and I see the data on the serial monitor. Now I would like to see this data online and they recommended Packet sender to send data packets but I can't. Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: This is way too broad question. Answer to your question depends on information which you did not share with us. Is it just hobby project with single device or should you support thousands of devices? Obviously you need to build/setup some server to receive data from your sensor, store history of values and to display data to the user. When you decide on back-end you can back here with specific question.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right.  It concerns a single device.  I would simply like to see the data I receive from the sensor, rather than from the serial monitor on the internet via WiFi.  So I agree with you once again on the server setup but I have seen several examples but I have not succeeded.  Thanks again

Comment: use a cloud service like thingspeak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you make your nodeMCU to work as a web server so that you can send/read data from it over your local network.

Here is a tutorial on web servers with nodeMCU:  https://lastminuteengineers.com/creating-esp8266-web-server-arduino-ide/?

If you want your device to be seen over the internet go for DDNS.